# Highlight a single line in a larger word-wrapped line

Tags: emacs

When using word wrap in emacs, long lines can be wrapped into shorter lines. The hl-line minor mode seems to highlight the whole wrapped line.

I would like to have only the one line highlighted in which the cursor is currently located. In the screen shot this would be the first line.

[image: Screenshot]

Which setting do I have to change?

Answer (score 1):

The `hl-line` mode allows to set a custom line defining function in hl-line-range-function.  That function gets to decide where a line starts and where it ends.  Just set it to something appropriate:

```
(defun visual-line-range ()
  (save-excursion
    (cons
     (progn (beginning-of-visual-line) (point))
     (progn (end-of-visual-line) (point)))))

(setq hl-line-range-function 'visual-line-range)
```

Voilà.